# A simple page of card-group with Angular and Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, angular

I have a page of card-group with bootstrap - it works :)
Then, I m trying to make the same page with a list of card from Angular and I can't succeed to have three cards in a row then next row.
Here is the code :

```
<div *ngIf="cartes">
  <div class="card-group" *ngFor="let c of cartes._embedded.cartes">
    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ c.nom }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ c.description }}}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ c.details }}</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

I think I'm missing something simple or related to bootstrap with Angular.

I tried moving `col-sm-4` in card -> doesn't work
I tried moving `*ngFor` in other place -> looks worse

I expect a display like this :

```
card1 - card 2 - card 3
card4 - card 5 - card 6
```

repeat using data

Comment: Show us the output you are getting .

Comment: you're looping in the `card-group`, instead of the `col-sm-4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="cartes">
  <div class="card-group" >
    <div class="col-sm-4  mb-2" *ngFor="let c of cartes._embedded.cartes">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ c.nom }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ c.description }}}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ c.details }}</a>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

*ngFor whould be on div with class "col-sm-4" because you have to repeat that div not the one above it.